# Can intron become exon in alternative splicing?

Tags: gene-expression, exons, isoforms

From this image [image]

We can see several exons that are actually introns in other genes. It's not a really a different gene, it's an alternative splicing of a gene. My background is not biology so is it possible for alternative splicing to behave like this? I only know that alternative splicing is just exon skipping and introns will just stay introns and not become exons. Can someone explain this to me and give any suggestions on which part of biology (or genetics) I need to learn. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If a portion of sequence ends up in the mature RNA, it is by definition not an intron.

Comment: Hmm, you are right. So, do you think from that picture, it's just exon skipping? What does that kind of gene called? Is it still called isoform? I have a hard time to do RNA-seq analysis for this gene because of overlap position near the end can be mapped to 9 gene.

Comment: Just did some brief reading. It seems each form is under the control of its own promoter. This means that A8 will have to splice out the first exons of all other forms (this would be exon skipping). On the other hand, the A1 pre-mRNA doesn't contain any other first exons to begin with. These would be classified as gene isoforms.

Comment: Thank you. Can you suggest where you read those explanation? My knowledge in biology is really limited so I need to read many material to improve my knowledge.

Comment: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene?Db=gene&Cmd=ShowDetailView&TermToSearch=54658

Comment: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/16399340/

Comment: Thank you so much. So, all of those gene will share 4 exon and just different in the first exon right? Does it mean, if I can count the reads of the first exon, I can estimate to total count of the gene (for example UGT1A1). Because the problem is the result for the last 4 exon is ambigous.

Comment: I don't know a lot about the analysis of RNA-seq data, but that sounds plausible to me.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the transcripts you show have different transcription start sites. In other words, this happens because of alternative transcription start sites. So this is not typical alternative slicing. Some genes have different transcriptional start sites, but the case you show has exceptionally many start sites.

Answer (score 1):

If a portion of sequence ends up in the mature RNA, it is by definition not an intron (save for abnormal splicing events and rare intron retention).

Specific to your question, it seems each form is under the control of its own promoter. This means that A8 will have to splice out the first exons of all other forms (this would be exon skipping). On the other hand, the A1 pre-mRNA doesn't contain any other first exons to begin with. These would be classified as gene isoforms

> **References:**
>
> [Owens IS, Basu NK, Banerjee R. 2005. UDP-glucuronosyltransferases: gene structures of UGT1 and UGT2 families. Methods Enzymol 400:1-22.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/16399340/)
>
> [NCBI Gene: UGT1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene?Db=gene&Cmd=ShowDetailView&TermToSearch=54658)