# Are Protocadherin Gamma Cluster transcripts considered separate genes?

Tags: genomics

The PDCH@ cluster of genes share exons and are therefore isoforms of each other.  However, they are considered [separate genes](https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?db=hg19&position=chr5%3A140728138-140915780&hgsid=438814847_MGLYAPcsVAFz7gTirswLCSXCrZ1h), by both HUGO and Ensembl.

A "gene" is defined as "a locus of co-transcribed exons" (Venter 2001), and this locus clearly fits that definition with no ambiguity. So **why are these transcripts considered separate genes?**

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: The question is, why are these transcripts considered separate genes?

Comment: Thanks, I slightly modified the question to improve clarity. Feel free to roll back. You may want to add a link to Venter, 2001 too. And transcripts are not genes.

Comment: Related: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/31766/can-intron-become-exon-in-alternative-splicing/

Answer (score 1):

I would say they are considered different genes because [each isoform is under the control of its own promoter](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/12154121/).

Comment: Having multiple promoters doesn't mean isoforms are different genes.  E.g., http://www.pnas.org/content/97/5/2291.full